# Upload file from URL to Microsoft Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, azure, url, upload

It is not a problem to upload file from local path (from my computer). However, I didn't find how to upload from specific URL.

If it possible - solution in Python is needed. There is documentation only for local files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

How to do this for remote URL?

Answer (score 9):

You can make use of `async copy blob` functionality to create a blob from a publicly accessible URL. Please see sample code below:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
from azure.storage.blob.models import Blob

def run_sample():
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='your_name', account_key='your_key')
    container_name ='t1s'

    block_blob_service.copy_blob(container_name,'remoteURL.pdf','https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/azure-storage/v0.20.3/azure-storage.pdf')


# Main method.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_sample()
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed, for relatively small files it works. Does it work with large files? For example, 100GB. I tried to do this, and the file was partially uploaded to storege.

Answer (score 2):

You can `first download the file as stream`, then call the method `create_blob_from_stream`.

The following is a demo code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
from azure.storage.blob.models import Blob
import requests

def run_sample():
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='your_name', account_key='your_key')
    container_name ='t1s'

    response = requests.get('https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/azure-storage/v0.20.3/azure-storage.pdf',stream=True)       
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream(container_name,'remoteURL.pdf',response.raw)


# Main method.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_sample()
```

Test result as below:
[image]

Comment: Actually that's not correct. One can use copy blob to create a block blob from any publicly accessible URL. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `upload_blob_from_url` function from the BlobClient class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-upload-blob-from-url

Example

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)

def upload_blob_from_url(container_name,blob_name,source_url):
    blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    blob.upload_blob_from_url(source_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oke, one additional information because I was confused when I saw this script.

Information for account_name and account_key you can find on portal.azure.com:

Resource Groups --> Select Resource Group where is Blob Storage --> Select Storage Account --> Click on Access Key from left panel.

account_name=Storage account name (like: mybackupstorage)

account_key=Key (like: ihwIKU@Hsniq87dbki*&qlos8ejuwa3ox7w4rykwij7ryx83deozd)

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
from azure.storage.blob.models import Blob
import requests

def run_sample():
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='', account_key='')
    container_name ='container-name'

    response = requests.get('https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/azure-storage/v0.20.3/azure-storage.pdf',stream=True)       
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream(container_name,'remoteURL.pdf',response.raw)


# Main method.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_sample()
```