# Saving scraped data directly to azure blob storage with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

My needs are the following:

I need to scrape the data from the webpage using azure functions, and save the scraping output directly to the azure blob storage as a .csv or .parquet.

Please see the example code:

```
response = requests.get('example_url')
        json_response = response.json()
        name = json_response.get('name', 'N/A')
        with open('warsaw.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(name)
```

How can i write the `f` directly into the azure blob storage, using `Blob Service Client`?

Comment: I think you should use Python SDK for Azure, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to scrape the data from the webpage using azure functions, and
> save the scraping output directly to the azure blob storage as a .csv
> or .parquet.

I think you can use 'append' method to achieve your requirement:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, BlobType
try:
    connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=1123bowman;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    container_name = "test"
    blob_name = "test.txt"
    data1 = "\n1,2,3"
    data = str.encode(data1)
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    print("length of data is "+str(len(data)))
    blob_client.append_block(data,length=len(data))
except:
    connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=1123bowman;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    container_name = "test"
    blob_name = "test.txt"
    data1 = "test1,test2,test3"
    data = str.encode(data1)
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    print("length of data is "+str(len(data)))
    blob_client.upload_blob(data,blob_type=BlobType.AppendBlob)
```

Through the above method, you don’t have to store the entire blob every time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Azure Storage Blobs client library for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-python)

Example on howto upload a file to Azure Storage Blobs:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="<connection_string>", container_name="my_container", blob_name="my_blob")

with open("./warsaw.txt", "rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data)
```

Comment: I think that he should directly save output to blob, without creating `warsaw.txt` file

Comment: tried doing that, but that means i firstly need to save scraping content into the txt file, then read it again with 'rb' mode and transfer it to blob storage. 
While doing that i get an exception sying that warsaw.txt is a read only file :c

Comment: Oh okay, I found another answer, that should solve your problem. [Uploading to Blob as stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182706/4954687)

Comment: This would work if i would need to save the whole response to the file, however firstly i need to extract data from the response to a variable, then save the data from the variable as csv or txt. Thanks though!